# Restrict user from accessing document library through URL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In SP 2007, I have custom control to create/edit/delete tasks. When a task is created, a separate folder is created in Documents Library by the name of task id.

Now, create/edit/delete access for tasks are checked in the custom controls itself. So if a user have edit access on the task then only he/she can attach the documents.

Now problem is user can easily go the URL `http://site/Documents/task_id` to access the attachment folder and can upload docs even if no edit access. Since its not a custom control, we cannot have customized access check there.

How to have a customized access check when user access document lib via URL?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to check if the user is accessing the document library via URL, then you could add a web part on the page folder page. For example, if you create a separate folder inside the document library each time a task is created, then the I assume the URL would be:

```
http://yoursite.com/DoclibName/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder={task_id}
```

Then on the AllItems.aspx of that document library, you could add a custom web part, which check if the request has referrer (clicked through link, button, etc.)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Request.UrlReferrer == null)
       return Response.Redirect("http://yoursite.com/NotFound.aspx");

   // Code if the user access this page through link
}
```